# Selenium - how it is able to recognize where my browser is installed?

Tags: java, selenium, browser

I just started learning of selenium webdriver and I'm wondering how it is able to find intall path of selected browser.

For example if I want to use FF to open some url it looks like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://bugs.casenetllc.com:9093/browse/CP-88661");
```

End I wonder how it is able to open FF without specifying the install path because default install path is not being used always.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I think you should read selenium doc first. Because this is not an question to ask before searching for it. You can ask question in which you got problem. see more [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [FirefoxDriver docs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver):

Normally the Firefox binary is assumed to be in the default location for your particular operating system:

- Linux: `firefox` (found using `which`)
- Mac:  `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin`
- Windows   `%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`

To override this behavior, set `webdriver.firefox.bin` system property.

Comment: I suppose that I can expect the same behavior for other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out that the selenium is being developed with firefox and for other browsers you need to download third party application which will create additional interface between selenium and browser. It can be downloaded here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/.